# SQL including count and multiple where clauses

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

Table `text_to_annotate`:

```
CREATE TABLE text_to_annotate (
ID varchar(3),
text varchar(100));

INSERT INTO text_to_annotate (ID, text)
VALUES 
(1, test1),
(2, test2),
(3, test3);
```

Table `annotation_data`:

```
CREATE TABLE annotation_data (
text_ID varchar(3),
annotation_ID varchar(3)
IP varchar(15));

INSERT INTO annotation_data (text_ID, annotation_ID, IP)
VALUES 
(1, 0, IP_1),
(2, 1, IP_1),
(3, 2, IP_1),
(1, 1, IP_2),
(2, 2, IP_2),
(3, 3, IP_2),
(3, 0, IP_3),
(3, 0, IP_4),
(3, 2, IP_5);
```

I want to display an unseen text to an annotator which hasn't been annotated more than 5 times. For example, a new annotator with `IP = IP_6` cannot annotate `text_ID = 3`, only `text_ID = 1` and `text_ID = 2`. An annotator can only annotate unique `text_ID`s once.

Here's my code, but something isn't quite correct:

```
SELECT text_to_annotate.ID, text_to_annotate.text 
FROM text_to_annotate
WHERE text_to_annotate.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT text_ID, count(*)
    FROM annotation_data
    WHERE IP = '{$ip}'
    AND GROUP BY text_ID
    HAVING count(*) > 1;
)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: You tell *more than **5** times* but use *HAVING count(\*) > **1***..

Comment: You don't put `AND` before `GROUP BY`. `AND` is used to combine multiple conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Having removed the `AND` and changed the count to be < 5, it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer:

```
SELECT text_to_annotate.ID, text_to_annotate.text 
FROM text_to_annotate
WHERE text_to_annotate.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT text_ID, count(*)
    FROM annotation_data
    WHERE IP = '{$ip}'
)
AND text_to_annotate.ID IN (
    SELECT text_ID FROM impact_annotation 
    GROUP BY text_ID 
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 5
)

ORDER BY RAND()
```